# VirtualBox - Centos Server. Can access https but not http

Tags: http, https, centos, webserver, virtualbox

So I'm setting up a vm on virtualbox with Centos. I was able to configure everything fine and with a bridge connection, I have access to the internet and the VM has an IP within the network. From the host I can ssh into the vm without a problem. Now here's the issue, for some reason if I load up the gui from the browser I can access https sites but not http sites.

I noticed this after I tried to install some applications but all mirrors were timing out. Anyone have any clue what this could be?